# Error al realizar dos consultas al mismo tiempo en MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT A.idProfesor, P.Nombre, IFNULL(sum(A.Inscrito),0) T1 FROM alumnos A 
LEFT JOIN profesores P ON A.idProfesor = P.idProfesor WHERE A.Inicia BETWEEN '2020-02-01' 
AND '2020-02-29' GROUP BY A.idProfesor ORDER BY P.Nombre ASC

  UNION

SELECT A.idProfesor, P.Nombre, COUNT(*) Inscrito FROM alumnos A LEFT JOIN profesores P 
ON A.idProfesor = P.idProfesor WHERE A.Inicia BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29' 
AND A.Inscrito = 0 GROUP BY A.idProfesor ORDER BY P.Nombre ASC
```

> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'UNION'

```
SELECT A.idProfesor, P.Nombre, COUNT(*) Inscrito FROM alumnos A LEFT JO' en la linea 3
```

Comment: Prueba eliminar la clausula de `order`de la primer sentencia.

Comment: Al ejecutar la consulta me manda el siguiente error: #1250 - Tabla 'P' de uno de los SELECT no puede ser usada en ORDER clause

Comment: El `order` debe ir únicamente en el último select del union

Comment: Parecería que una consulta de `UNION` no es justificada en este caso... ¿qué es lo que quieres lograr con esta consulta?

Comment: La primera consulta es para saber cuantos alumnos están inscritos con un profesor y la segunda es para saber cuantos alumnos no están inscritos con ese profesor

Comment: Debes especificar también que es lo que debe realizar tu consulta, revisar [ask] @Zack

Answer (score 0):

Si usas [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) , agrega cada bloque entre paréntesis, ejemplo:

```
(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;
```

No estas definiendo  en que tabla se encuentra el campo Inscrito :  `...  Inscrito ...` , debe ser `A.Inscrito`

Si usas [COUNT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-count/) de un campo especifico esto es incorrecto: `COUNT(*) Inscrito` , debes agregar el campo del cual deseas obtener el conteo `COUNT(Inscrito)`

Esta sería la consulta:

```
(
  SELECT
    A.idProfesor,
    P.Nombre,
    IFNULL(sum(A.Inscrito), 0) T1
  FROM
    alumnos A
    LEFT JOIN profesores P ON A.idProfesor = P.idProfesor
  WHERE
    A.Inicia BETWEEN '2020-02-01'
    AND '2020-02-29'
  GROUP BY
    A.idProfesor
  ORDER BY
    P.Nombre ASC
)
UNION
  (
    SELECT
      A.idProfesor,
      P.Nombre,
      COUNT(A.Inscrito)
    FROM
      alumnos A
      LEFT JOIN profesores P ON A.idProfesor = P.idProfesor
    WHERE
      A.Inicia BETWEEN '2020-02-01'
      AND '2020-02-29'
      AND A.Inscrito = 0
    GROUP BY
      A.idProfesor
    ORDER BY
      P.Nombre ASC
  )
```

Comment: Al realizar la consulta no me esta mandado los registros del COUNT

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta se basa en que el query es incorrecto y no puede ser ejecutado, si deseas una respuesta más amplia debes especificar que es lo que debe realizar tu consulta, revisar [ask] @Zack